# Eloquent ORM check IFNULL() in GET()

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using `LARAVEL 4` with `MySQL` back-end. I am novice to it.

I have a statement that returns records from 3 different tables as below :

```
$templates = Template::with('children')
                    ->leftJoin('template_masters', function($join) {
                        $join->on('templates.template_master_id', '=', 'template_masters.id');
                    })
                    ->leftJoin('surveyes', function($join) {
                        $join->on('templates.survey_id', '=', 'surveyes.id');
                    })
                    ->get([
                    'templates.id',
                    'templates.survey_id',
                    'surveyes.title', // Here I want the IFNULL() condition e.g. IFNULL('surveyes.title','templates.title')
                    'templates.type',
                    'templates.created_at',
                    'template_masters.is_default'
                    ]);
```

Basically this creates a query something like :

```
select `templates`.`id`, 
    `templates`.`survey_id`, 
    `surveyes`.`title`, 
    `templates`.`type`, 
    `templates`.`created_at`, 
    `template_masters`.`is_default` 
from `templates` 
    left join `surveyes` on `templates`.`survey_id` = `surveyes`.`id` 
    left join `template_masters` on `templates`.`template_master_id` = `template_masters`.`id`
```

But I want this query like :

```
select `templates`.`id`, 
    `templates`.`survey_id`, 
     IFNULL(`surveyes`.`title`, `templates`.`title`),
    `templates`.`type`, 
    `templates`.`created_at`, 
    `template_masters`.`is_default` 
from `templates` 
    left join `surveyes` on `templates`.`survey_id` = `surveyes`.`id` 
    left join `template_masters` on `templates`.`template_master_id` = `template_masters`.`id`
```

In short, instead of `surveyes`.`title`, I want `IFNULL(`surveyes`.`title`,`templates`.`title`)`.

How can I achieve this in `->GET([])` statement of given `Eloquent ORM`?

Thanks.

Comment: use `DB::raw('ifnull(...)')` instead of `surveys.title` within `get`

Comment: I am getting "DB" not found error.

Comment: \DB::raw('ifnull(...)'), :) Thanks. Now, other problem due to this is I am getting "IFNULL(surveyes.title, template_masters.title)" as a KEY instead of just "title". How to overcome from this?

Comment: @deczo \DB::raw('IFNULL(surveyes.title, template_masters.title) as title'). This worked for me. If you paste this as answer, I will accept it. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use raw statement:

```
...
->get([
  'templates.id',
  'templates.survey_id',
  DB::raw('IFNULL(surveyes.title,template_masters.title) as title'),

  // or if you use namespace:
  \DB::raw('IFNULL(surveyes.title,template_masters.title) as title'),

  'templates.type',
  'templates.created_at',
  'template_masters.is_default'
]);
```